# Communication between objects through references

Tags: java, oop, reference

I've finally arrived at what has been my hugest dilemma in OOP while programming simple old school Snake in Java. It surely will sound trivial for you but I couldn't put this problem to words for a long time.

My question is about references between objects. What is a convention and a good practice when it comes to communicating objects? I mean, of course not every object should know about its creator for example, but in my case, I feel like there is no other way to communicate them with each other. For example:

I have MainMenu class that controls simple form with a "New Game" button. When the button is clicked there is a Game object created (with its own form) and MainMenu form is set to invisible while new Game object's form is set to visible. When the game is over I want to close game's form and make MainMenu form reappear. But reappearing happens inside Game object, so there must be a reference to this MainMenu object, so I passed it to the constructor but it feels wrong for me, because Game object shouldn't know about MainMenu, they are separate things, the only interest Game object has with MainMenu is to make it reappear after game is over and It just feels not enough reason to make the additional reference.

How should It have been done? I think reappearing should happen in MainMenu class, but how can I track game ending from there? How are this kind of problems solved in professional programming?

(Sorry for my English)

Comment: And what the problem is? If your program uses multithreading, you can use join(). Otherwise, the code executes sequentially and if you call a new method you have to wait until it's done. So, you can implement all needed logic in your MainMenu.

Comment: You are right, I just forgot about join(), as my Game is a thread it's actually the best thing to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an interface like `GameFinishHandler` and let `MainMenu` implement it. The `Game` class invokes all registered handler at the end of game.

```
interface GameFinishHandler {
    void doAfterGameFinished();
}

class MainMenu implements GameFinishHandler {
    ...

    private void createGame() {
        this.game = new Game();
        this.game.addHandler(this);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void doAfterGameFinished() {
        game.setVisible(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

class Game {
    private final List<GameFinishHandler> finishHandler = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addHandler(GameFinishHandler handler) {
        finishHandler.add(handler);
    }

    private void afterGameFinished() {
        finishHandler.forEach(GameFinishHandler::doAfterGameFinished);
    }
```

So your `Game` class holds a reference of your menu but it doesn't "know" it. It just holds any number of finish handler.

Comment: Is this solution also called the Observer Pattern? I think I've read about it few days ago.

Comment: No, it is not. If `Game` has a field like `boolean gameFinished` you can observe this value. That means the a change listener is invoked every time `gameFinished` changes. Since your game instance your game class changes this value only once I won't observe this value.